# Create a loop to label dates base on month without the use of many multiple 'case', 'between'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have code as below:

```
WHEN table.date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31' THEN 'january'
        WHEN table.date BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-02-28' THEN 'feb'
        WHEN table.date BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31' THEN 'march'
        WHEN table.date BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-30' THEN 'april'
        WHEN table.date BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31' THEN 'may'
        WHEN table.date BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-30' THEN 'june'
        WHEN table.date BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31' THEN 'july'
        WHEN table.date BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-08-31' THEN 'august'
```

is there a way to use loop so that it will loop from year 2010 - 2020? I do not want to create one by one from 2010 until 2020, it will be like 100++

Comment: What SQL database are you using here (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) ?  Most likely, your database already has a function for obtaining the month name from a date.

Comment: I am using SQLserver

Answer (score 4):

You should be using a date function which already exists in SQL Server. [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is one such option:

```
SELECT FORMAT(table.date, 'MMMM') AS month_name
FROM yourTable;
```

Note that your entire verbose `CASE` expression was replaced with a single function call, and also the above will also work for any date year.

If you are using an earlier version of SQL Server which might not support `FORMAT`, then use `DATENAME`:

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, table.date) AS month_name
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: thank you but I received this error. Error [42883 / 500310]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function format(date, "unknown") does not exist;

Comment: I received an error like : Error [42601 / 500310]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "table" Position: 35;

Can you tell me the arguments in the function representing what?

Comment: @Anony You need to tell us this; I am just using `table.date` as a placeholder.  Of course, your actual table name won't be `table`.

Comment: for example, my database name is 'aggregated_people'. SELECT DATENAME(month, aggregated_people.date) AS month_name
FROM aggregated_people;

Comment: Looks more like aggregated_people  is the table name.

Comment: my database contain column that is called 'date' and inside are strings like this '2019-02-20'

Comment: And what **DATATYPE** is your `date` column?? (Also: please **avoid** using T-SQL reserved keywords like `DATE` for your column names! Use something clearer - like `BirthDate`, `HireDate`, `SaleDate` etc. - not just an overly generic `Date`......)

Comment: but when I use your example and change the placeholder to aggregated_people.date. i received Error [42703 / 500310]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "month" does not exist in users_money;

Comment: the datatype is date

Comment: No reason to use potentially slow/inefficient FORMAT function. Just use built-in tsql function [datename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @SMor Yes, `FORMAT` is notoriously slow, but it has things like locale support which `DATENAME` does not have `:-)`